# Broadband router works for some devices but not others & some sites but not others

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I've recently switched ISP, and have a broadband modem/router provided by the new ISP.

My MacBook connects fine, and everything works as expected.

My iPhone connects to the router OK and gets an IP address, and can connect to the ISP's website, but not to other websites. Chrome just says `ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED`. iMessage and FaceTime work fine though.

If I switch to Boot Camp on the MacBook, it's the same as the phone - it connects to the router OK, but can only see the ISP's website.

The phone and the Boot Camp partition both work fine on other networks, so I don't think there's any problem with the devices.

I've tried a factory reset of the router, and switching the channel from automatic to specific channels, but nothing has made any difference.

Is there any explanation for a router working with some devices but not others, and allowing access to some sites but not others, or is the router just faulty?

Comment: Contact the ISP. It appears you must log into their site first, as at a public site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted my ISP and they told me to update the router's DNS settings. Previously the router was set to configure DNS automatically, but it's now manual, using `8.8.8.8` for the primary DNS, and `4.4.4.4` for the secondary.

So far, everything seems to be working OK, though they were unable to explain why the MacBook worked fine before...